# Parsing JSON iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON in iOS to get a URL from google. I've gotten pretty far (see code below), the problem is since I've never worked with JSON before, I'm not really sure how things are defined. How can I look for an object that's inside another object?

For example if I want to get the first `unescapedUrl` [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=monkey) how can I do that? I tried simply using objectForKey, but it didn't work.. I'm guessing I'm going to have to specify the exact path. How can I do that?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
    #define kLatestSearchURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=monkey"] //2

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
    +(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress;
    -(NSData*)toJSON;
    @end

    @implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
    +(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress
    {
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
        __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        if (error != nil) return nil;
        return result;
    }

    -(NSData*)toJSON
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        if (error != nil) return nil;
        return result;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestSearchURL];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
    }

    - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];

// ---------------------------- Will Start Parsing Here ------------------------------
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Peel the onion.  You can use a long, complex path expression, but, while learning JSON, you'll understand it better if you "peel" one layer at a time, and NSLog the result.  Keep in mind that NSLog presents the result slightly differently from JSON, with `()` instead of `{}`.  You can test what you have at any level with `if (myObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])` (or `NSArray` or `NSNumber` or `NSString` or whatever).

Answer (score 6):

God save literals (Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0 or later SDK, LLVM Compiler 4.0 required). Deploys back to iOS 5.

```
NSString *url = resp[@"responseData"][@"results"][0][@"unescapedUrl"];
```

Comment: Works on iOS 4.3 and 5.x too, just make sure you've got Xcode 4.4.

Comment: Subscripting requires iOS 5 or greater. See the Apple compatibility matrix [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/).

Comment: @Cyrille No it doesn't - the libraries on the iPhone miss the corresponding messages, it will crash with 'unrecognized selector'.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sure about iOS 5? I know that `@YES` and `@NO` don’t work until iOS6, but I'm not sure about subscripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `objectForKey:` for dictionaries and `objectAtIndex:` for arrays:

```
NSString *url = [[[[resp objectForKey:@"responseData"]
                        objectForKey:@"results"]
                        objectAtIndex:0]
                        objectForKey:@"unescapedUrl"];
```

Comment: *Works for iOS 2 or later.

Comment: Is there anyway to know how many people are still using iOS 2? And +1!

Comment: Haha! But I was actually looking for a somewhat more generic answer, like a link to a table or something Apple keeps up to date with how many users use what iOS (or how many iPhones what iOS have installed, Apple probably can't tell a difference). @HotLicks

Comment: @11684 - My point is that you'll hardly need to use your toes -- there are very few phones running the early versions, and those that are aren't buying new apps.